# Angular Material Tailwind clashes with scss

Tags: angular, angular-material, tailwind-css

When I installed Tailwind with an exiting Angular project including Angular Material (scss) many classes were not available - i.e. mt-60 as an example - though many others were.

To try and recreate the issue I created a new project and then installed Angular Material (specifying scss) then Tailwind. The same problems as before were encountered with missing classes.

I then created a second test project following the same steps but specifying css this time. All worked as expected and all classes were available to me.

**Update**

Adding `important: true` option into tailwind.config.js  fixed the issue.